# bloc eventController is closed unexpected

Tags: flutter, bloc

i´ve an app that should support responsive design.
In the mobile view I am using the scaffold drawer for the main menu:

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: title,
  ),
  drawer: MainMenuDrawer(),
  body: body,
);
```

In the desktop view the menu should always be visible, so i don´t use the drawer propery. Instead of that i´ve added the same menu as widget into a row:

```
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
       automaticallyImplyLeading: true ,
       title: title
      ),
      body: Row(
       children: [
         MainMenuDrawer(),
         Expanded(child: body),
       ],
      ),
    );
```

The menu has a logout button which sends an event to my authentication bloc and pops all pages from the navigation stack, to get to the first page (login page).

```
  authenticationBloc.add(AuthenticationEvent.loggedOut());
  while (Navigator.canPop(context)) {
     Navigator.pop(context);
```

}

The authentication bloc is as singleton:

```
@singleton
class AuthenticationBloc extends Bloc<AuthenticationEvent, AuthenticationState>
```

As long as i am using the mobile view, I can logout from everywhere and it´s works as expected.

But when I switch to the desktop view the logout button doesn´t work anymore.

In the debug mode, I can see, that the eventController of the authBloc is already closed, so no event is added:

```
  void add(Event event) {
    if (_eventController.isClosed) return; <- isClosed is true
```

Does anyone know why this happened in the desktop view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i´ve found the problen In the onTap method of my listitem.
To close the drawer i´ve called the Navigator.pop(context).
But this will cause the previous page to be closed when the menu is used as drawer.

Comment: Hello, I am facing the same issue, if bloc is singleton, how pop has any impact on this